# Make Drop-down Menu Push Content Down in WordPress Twenty Twelve

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

I want to modify CSS of WordPress Twenty Twelve theme in such a way that the drop-down submenu links push the rest of the content down.

I assume, I have to remove `position:absolute;` in CSS in the submenu ul li, however, for some reason, when I do that, the submenu still covers the div below it, instead of pushing it down.

I'd appreciate advice from someone WordPress-savvy!

Comment: Post code or a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: code, or a link of the website would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Adrift – would a link to a website work? (I'm not very good with jsfiddle, and there's too much code to post.)

Comment: That would be perfect ..

Comment: Sure - one thing though - when you say "push content down" do you mean the main image underneath the menu?

Comment: I mean, everything that's underneath the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked at the website, and i created sample menu from scratch.
I hope it will be helpful for you.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/dpGDe/1/).
Here is some HTML (i left out the `<a>` tags so it will be more readable.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="nav">
    <li>link1
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link2
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>link3
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
body
{
margin:0;
}
#wrapper
{
    background:#ccc;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav > li
{
    float:left;
}
#nav > li:hover .sub
{
    display:block;
}
.sub
{
    display:none;
}
.clear
{
clear:both;
}
```

I think you should be able to modify this to your needs.

---

here is step by step guide, but keep in mind that you need to do a lot more work to achieve the result you want. these are some basic steps.
for the nav:

```
.main-navigation {
    float: right; <- remove this line
    }
```

top ul:

```
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: inline-block !important;<- remove this line
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu, .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: none;<- remove this line
}
li:
.main-navigation li a, .main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;<- remove this line  
}


.main-navigation li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;<- remove this line
    top: 100%;
}

ul.nav-menu > li {<- add this rule
    float: left;
}
```

some changes in the html:

```
<div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
...
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div> <- add this line and the folowing rule in the css
</div>

.clear
{
clear:both;
}
```

create a backup from your older versions, and give it a try.

Comment: – thank you for the demo, that's the effect I want to achieve – but could you please tell me (which was my original question) – how to I recreate the same effect for the menu in Twenty Twelve WordPress theme? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use the same code(there is analogy), but from Twenty Twelve WordPress theme you'll have to remove the `positioning`, `floating` and `display:inline-block` and the similar things. after that, your website would look a bit different, so you'll have to modify the other styles in your website. and dont forget to add `<div class="clear"></div>` before closing `menu-main-menu-container` div, since that is one of the key things to make it work. also your `nav` `.main-navigation` has `float:right`, that has to be removed aswell.

Comment: and 1 advice, you will find it usefull if you make backup of your css before you make changes.

Comment: – could you please be a little more detailed? I've been trying to follow your advice for about an hour now, and I don't see how it can be applied to the much more complex css structure of the Twenty Twelve menu.

Comment: ill add up some css in few minutes. can you give me the link again?

Comment: – thank you very much! I appreciate the time you dedicated to helping me out. Could you please clarify, where in html is this bit supposed to be placed: <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">...
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
...
</ul>

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks a lot, @trajce!

Answer (score -1):

Try `position : relative;` instead of `position : absolute;`